# Error message "You do not have sufficient privilege to save LotusScript or Java agents." in Domino Designer

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

When trying to edit a Java agent in Domino Designer, I got this error message. Some months ago I could still edit Java agents, and I didn't do anything that might have changed that.

I can still login into the Designer and view and edit agents there, I just cannot save them.

Possible causes:

- My user certificate has expired. I looked up my account in the Domino Administrator, and I couldn't find any expiration date.

What could have possibly happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the sufficient right in database's ACL:

[image]

Ask your administrator to set the privilege "Create LotusScript/Java agents" for you.

Comment: My real scenario was a little more complicated. I had accidentally opened a different database than I had expected, but with the same name. After choosing the correct database, everything worked fine.